# Big-O of a while loop in Java

Tags: java, while-loop, big-o

I was wondering what the Big-O of this code is

```
static boolean mysterious(int[] w) {
    int anz = w.length;
    int i = 0;
    int j = anz - 1;

    while (i < j) {
        if (w[i] != w[j]) {
            return false;
        }
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I would say it's O(j) but I am not quite sure.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's O(w.length) actually. worst case, your while loop will execute w.length/2 times which in big o notation we consider as O(w.length)

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation. You don't have to thank in comments, simply upvote/accept answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can speak here of the best/worst case performance.  The best case performance is `O(1)`, and would occur if the first and last elements of the array input were not equal.

In the worst case, there would be `N/2` iterations of the `while` loop.  This would occur if the number array did not contain any sub array about the middle element which were not a palindrome.  So in the worst case, the function is `O(N)`, where `N` is the length of the array.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you so much Tim!

Comment: @Dominic Actually, it helps to comment on what your method is actually doing.  It's checking whether an array of input numbers is a palindrome.

Comment: I'm probably lacking in understanding the Big-O notation.  But as I see it, as a worst case notation. When w.length = 4 you get 2 iterations.  6 elements -> 3 iterations, 8 elements ->4 iterations, etc. So why isn't it O(N/2) ?

Comment: @LukStorms The input array could be massive, but if `w[0] != w[N-1]`, then the loop would just have one iteration in the best case.

Answer (score 1):

`i` and `j` start pointing at either end of the array `w` and `i` moves forward while `j` moves back. At each step, we compare the elements referred to by `i` and `j`. So, it is `O(w.length)` asymptotically

Comment: Thank you so much user7!